# Filter data by multiple fields and random field without full table scan

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

I am creating a filter on table.For efficient filtering i am using  multiple column index approach .

Suppose my table has following fields.

```
   field_A  |  field_B       |  field_C   |  field_D
------------------------------------------------------
   1        |  346           |  934       |  659
   2        |  709           |  497       |  24
   3        |  835           |  853       |  73
   4        |  325           |  935       |  45
   5        |  346           |  287       |  345
```

Query work fine if field_A is prefix in the filter query. Such as following order work fine.

```
 1. field_A
 2. field_A  field_B
 3. field_A  field_B  field_C
 4. field_A  field_B  field_C  field_D
```

But index not work if i have combination of fields other then that.

1. field_B  field_D
2. field_B  field_C
3. field_C  field_D
4. Or any other random combination

I know that it is working fine according to multiple column index definition.

What i want to know is there any other approach that i can use to filter by fields in random order without going throw full table scan. All fields has integer data type

Comment: You can create multiple indices. That would slightly increase the insertion times. Otherwise go with Solr/Lucene for full text random searches.

Comment: what do you mean by multiple indices?

Comment: Indices on (field_B,field_D), (field_B,field_C), (field_C, field_D) based on what you are going to query on.

Comment: That is so worst case